# Checkstyle-IDEA IntelliJ plugin not showing problems when it should

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have noticed that my local IntelliJ Checkstyle-IDEA plugin is not highlighting any errors in my code, whereas when I run "mvn clean install" or similar it (correctly) highlights the problems.

I am using a custom checkstyle file, but since this is working through maven, I'm guessing this isn't the problem? Also, I have tried other xml files, and I get the same result.

I'm not quite sure where to start here. I have tried the classic reinstall of the plugin, different PCs etc. Can someone point me in a direction...?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
```

Comment: I think that this would have been more appropriate as a comment, not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away by upgrading IntelliJ to v2020.1.1, and updating the plugin to the latest version. Not very satisfactory, but at least it works now...

Answer (score 0):

I'd same problem but noticed that this happens only when google checks is selected as rules. When sun checks is selected, I can see the errors. Accepted answer to question below may help you.

[maven-checkstyle-plugin not working with google_checks.xml on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185954/maven-checkstyle-plugin-not-working-with-google-checks-xml-on-macos)